# How to use PrinceXML to align a div to the bottom of a page in a PDF

Tags: princexml

I have a div that renders on multiple versions of PDFs (using HTML and PrinceXML) and I am wondering how to align that div to the bottom of its page.

I have tried the float and such in the prince docs but cannot find any solution that works.

-prince-float: page;
-prince-clear: end;

Chrome does not seem to register those attributes.

Also tried:

flow: static(flow-prince-footer)

Not really sure what to do!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you neet to add the following to your css

@page { @bottom { content:  'My footer at the bottom of the page'; font: bold 6pt 'tahoma', 'sans-serif';  } }

Comment: Thank you! This worked!

Comment: Can you mark as answered?